# Is it ok to put the one main package in a cmd/myapp subdirectory?

Tags: go

this is my first Go project and I have had a hard time grasping the different documents on code organization (e.g. I found it somewhat hard to tell which ones have been superceded, or apply to deprecated vendoring tools/approaches). I finally settled on Ben Johnson's [Standard Package Layout](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1), with a very slim root package (in the root directory of my project) and most code in internal/pkg/...

However, I've added a cmd/myapp dir and put my main.go file for the executable program in there, since I understood that to be a common pattern.

So now I have:

```
myapp
|
+- myapp.go   // "package myapp", with only type and interface declarations and no imports
|
+- cmd
|   |
|   +- main.go // "package main", with import gitlab.tld/username/myapp, gitlab.tld/username/myapp/internal/pkg/routing etc.
|
+- internal
    |
    +- pkg
        |
        +- routing
        |    |
        |    +- routing.go // "package routing"
        |
        +- sql 
        |
        +- etc.
```

Now, when I go to cmd/myapp and call `go build`, it builds fine and leaves an executable that does what it's supposed to do right there. But when I call `go build -v` from the project's main directory, no executable is produced. In fact, only myapp.go seems to be processed which contains only type definitions. (And of course, `go install` does not produce a binary either. `go get -v gitlab.tld/username/myapp` also does not seem to do anything.)

So I have the suspicion that this is not how it is meant after all, but I am not even so sure about that. Is there a problem with the project layout, or did I get the usage of go tooling wrong?

Thanks for any help you might provide to this go newbie,

Andreas

Comment: This guideline is very useful (and many official Go tools follow it) https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout

Comment: Thanks. I know the guideline and in fact, this is (some of) what made me move the source for my executable to cmd/. Only I end up with no main package in the project's root and a simple `go build`/`go install` from the project's root will not do anything. But as far as I understand it now, based on @dev.bmax's answer, actually that is nothing to be afraid of. I will probably script building the cmd/myapp/main.go and then moving it to some other place where it is more easily accessible. (And where it more easily finds the relevant config file.)

Comment: You are right. And the structure is used mostly for multi command (set of) tools. But it has useful semantics like if another package tries to import from `internal` packages of this project, it will produce a compilation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `go build` or `go install` the command expects a list of packages to process. If no import paths are given, the action applies to the package in the current directory.

So if there is no `package main` in your root directory, no executable will be produced.

The command doesn't look in subdirectories. You may have multiple commands in your `cmd` directory. In this case it won't know which one to build. And building all of them every time is wasteful.

Comment: So having no "main" package in the project's root directory is not a problem and building with `go build cmd/myapp` (or install) is not so uncommon or even absurd. I think I will still copy the binary to some other place (manually or with a kind of build script), but that's no problem actually. Also, reading more I found out that the project as a whole is perfectly go-gettable - when you `go get gitlab.tld/username/myapp/...` **with the three dots at the end**. So my worries about organizing it all wrong after all are somewhat attenuated. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.